# Can't connect to my wlan router but can connect to any other router (but router works fine with other distributions)

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, network-manager

Suddenly after Ubuntu freeze I am unable to connect to my router. I have already reset my router but nothing has happend. If i connect my Ubuntu with my Android wlan router it works fine. I have tried lot of  things: changed router setting, restarted network-manager, deleted old networks and there is no black list on my router, turned off power management etc. but it still doesn't work with my router. On the other hand I'm able to connect with my router from other Linux distributions like mint from other computers. Router also works fine with win7 OS.

It's very confusing!

I have technicolor router from upc. My Wlan0: Ralink Technology RT2501/RT2573.

So again it works fine with other router (android mobile) but not with technicolor. But technicolor works fine with Mint, Win7 and Android devices but not only with Ubuntu.

**Answer1: Laurent**  Ubuntu 12.04.04

```
$ifconfig 
     Wlan0: Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:12:bf:c4:8c:f2 
     inet6 addr: fe80::212:bfff:fec4:8cf2/64 Scope:Link
     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
     RX packets:37 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
     RX bytes:5681 (5.6 KB)  TX bytes:26298 (26.2 KB)
```

"**Answer comment-1:Parto**"  youtube but true :) with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>print</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (R E I S U B)
 Good point, I think that would be a problem. Because right after rebooting I was unable to connect to my router. But I have checked couple of config files & compared thier output on forums. But I must have missed somthing.

**Booted** yes, I have rebooted couple of times. Still there is same problem.

```
$ rfkill list Output  
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: What caused the ubuntu freeze you mention and how did you resolve it?

Comment: youtube but true :) with alt+print+B (R E I S U B)

Comment: Please provide more info by using the comments not editing the question, see [this question in stack exchange meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) for why.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting Ubuntu?

Comment: More than 10 times.

Comment: What's the output of `rfkill list`

Comment: 0: phy0: Wirless LAN  Soft  blocked :no Hard blocked: no

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14130/discussion-between-parto-and-user14466)

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 0):

On which version of Ubuntu are you working ?
Have you tried to

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager nm-applet
```

and then

> sudo apt-get install network-manager nm-applet

Can you please type in your terminal

> ifconfig

and paste here the output ?

Comment: Wlan0: Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:12:bf:c4:8c:f2 

      inet6 addr: fe80::212:bfff:fec4:8cf2/64 Scope:Link

      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

      RX packets:37 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

      TX packets:112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
Ubuntu 12.04.04 --- ifconfig 
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 

      RX bytes:5681 (5.6 KB)  TX bytes:26298 (26.2 KB)

Comment: @user14466: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: You are a 170-rep user, you can comment so please request details in comments.